# less css via ruby on win 7 - ver greater than 1.2.21?

Tags: css, ruby, windows, rubygems, less

Is there a way to get any of the 2.x versions working via Ruby on Windows?

I tested all the versions listed via `gem list --remote --all less`

The problem is that I can only install the 1.2.21 version, which doesn't support the & less selector.

So i have to do

```
div {
    border: red;
}
div.blue {
    border: blue;
}
```

instead of

```
div {
     border: red;
     &.blue {
         border: blue;
     }
}
```

Which is quite annoying...

Any help greatly appreciated.

Regards,
PM

Comment: i also have virtualbox installed, but dunno if I can access my own filesystem via a virtual pc (with linux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a way (well, two) and would like to share. Hope this helps someone and saves him tons of searching.

The one I'm going with is using [node.js](http://nodejs.org/). Would use ruby only for this, so it's irelevant which one I'll use.
It's perfectly described there: [vertstudios.com/blog/less-app-windows-sorta](http://www.vertstudios.com/blog/less-app-windows-sorta/) and works like a charm.

After editing their less.js for a while to fit my dir structure it's brilliant. It supports everything, outputs minifed/compressed version and has a watch functionality.

Another way (which isn't as convenient) is using windows's csript. Described on [Christopher Bennage's blog](http://devlicio.us/blogs/christopher_bennage/archive/2011/07/28/node-js-on-windows.aspx)